PM2 clustered NestJS application stops without errors after starting
I am trying to run my NestJS project in clustered mode using PM2. I am using the following command:
pm2 start ecosystem.config.js

Here is the content of the ecosystem.config.js file:
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'td',
      script: 'dist/main.js',
      instances: '2',
      exec_mode: 'cluster',
    },
  ],
};

In my main.js file, I have the following logic:
async function bootstrap() {
  process.setMaxListeners(0);
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
    cors: { origin: '*', credentials: true, optionsSuccessStatus: 200 },
    httpsOptions,
  });
  await app.listen(process.env.PORT);
  
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'dev') {
    const httpServer = createServer();
    const io = new Server(httpServer);
    io.adapter(createAdapter());
    setupWorker(io);
    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
      console.log(`connect ${socket.id}`);
    });
  }
}

The project starts, but it soon stops without throwing any errors, and when I run the pm2 status command, the list is empty.
What could be causing PM2 to stop the application without any error logs? How can I debug or fix this issue?
Here are a few things I've tried so far:

Reduced the number of clusters to 2 to reduce the load.
Checked the log file but found nothing unusual.
When I run the application without clusters, everything works fine.
The project runs without issues on my local machine.

